# How hide blocks

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

There are 11 blocks, each with a minimum width of 100px, in one line, the width of the parent is 100% of the screen.
How to arrange blocks in the full width of the parent, while changing the resolution, blocks that do not fit entirely are not transferred, but hidden completely ***

```css
.item {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 110px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;

}

section{
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</section>
```

[image]***, illustration and my code below:

Comment: Do you want to show all 11 blocks visible in any resolution?

Comment: You will need javascript for this.

Comment: Do you want to show all 11 blocks visible in any resolution? Yes. then it possible. Min-width of blocks is 110px and padding 16px, on the small screen nlocks that do not fit entirely are not transferred must hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS grid for this:

```css
.item {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

section{
  overflow: hidden;
  height:50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill,minmax(110px,1fr));
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's any easy way to do what you're talking about with just CSS. You have to take screen size and according to that hide the rest of the block.